# Getting error while implementing a project to start spring cloud dataflow server on local

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am implementing very basic POC to start spring cloud dataflow server on local.
But I am getting below error :

> Field appRegistry in
> org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.completion.CompletionConfiguration
> required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.registry.service.AppRegistryService'
> that could not be found. The injection point has the following
> annotations:
> -@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ms</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>abc-ui</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.193</h2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Java file :

```
@EnableDataFlowServer
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {CloudFoundryDeployerAutoConfiguration.class})
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class,args);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to disable "AppRegistry" bean configuration?
I have implemented same project in another system and it is working fine.
Please let me know what mistake I am making.

Answer (score 0):

The `AppRegistryService` is a required component for SCDF as it is the source of truth for all the applications registered for Stream and Task applications.

Hence, there is no way to disable it explicitly. But, you can still have a different implementation of `AppRegistryService` and have it override the existing one though.

Comment: i dont want to provide custom implementation, i have no such requirement..but it is asking me o do that...can you suggest how I can use default one?